# Solution to integral of $n^{x^2}$

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I am trying to derive the integral of a function where the $x$ term is not a power but a power and squared.

I.e.
$$y=n^{x^2}$$
Which similarly would be:
$$y =(n^x)^x$$

Similarly, a solution for the derivative would be of interest too.

Hoping there is someone who can shed some light on this for me.

Comment: You are likely out of luck since $n^{x^2} = \mathrm{e}^{x^2\ln n}$ which we can rescale to $\mathrm{e}^{t^2}$. Which does not permit an analytical solution.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you mean integral or derivative? You wrote "integral" in the text but also wrote "dy/dx" which seems to indicate you mean derivative.

Comment: @Carl - text edited. I meant integral as stated. My mistake. (Haven't entirely got to grips with the equation formatting on here either - thanks Parcly for the edit above also)

Comment: Of course it has an "analytical" solution, in terms of the imaginary error function $\text{erfi}$.  What it is not is "elementary function".  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: @GEdgar my words were loose - I meant the later of your statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the integral, you won't get a nice, clean solution. As pointed out in the comments,

$$\int n^{x^2} {\rm d}x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln n}} \int e^{t^2} {\rm d}t$$

using the transformation $t = \sqrt{\ln n}\,x$. Integrals of squared exponentials tend to be messy. For a list of common integrals of this type, have a look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions). The entry for $\int e^{x^2}{\rm d}x$ is in the [Indefinite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Other_integrals) section.

For the derivative, you can apply the chain rule.

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} n^{x^2}
&= (\ln n)\,n^{x^2} \frac{d}{dx} x^2 \\
&= (2x \ln n) \, n^{x^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Many thanks for the direction on this

Comment: @ShaunMc If you are happy with the answer then you should accept it :)